# Where to find Encog 2 or Programming Neural Networks with Encog 3 in Java, 2nd Edition free

Tags: java, frameworks, neural-network

I'm new to Encog and while I was reading **Programming Neural Networks with Encog 2 in Java** I couldn't find classes such as ContextLayer in Encog 3 and further it seems like encog 3 is considerably diffenet from encog 2... So can anyone please tell me where to find Encog 2 or where to download **Programming Neural Networks with Encog 3 in Java, 2nd Edition** from....

Thanx...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old encog 2 is [still on google code](http://code.google.com/p/encog-java/downloads/list).

The encog 3 book is commercial; if you want to find a place to download it for free, you're on your own. I'm not sure if the first edition is (legitimately) available as a free download.